# jQuery: don't repeat animation when mouse is still / don't safe animation queue / stop animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

This is more or less a basic jQuery-Question.

The following is my problem:

I have a mouseenter-function. so when I enter the specific container, an animation starts. the problem is, when i enter this container for example 10 times in a few seconds, then the animation is repeated and repeated… but i only want it one time… hope you understand.

here is an video to demonstrate my problem: 
http://youtu.be/5Cb0qHKtl_c

Or look here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/meNK5/

```
$('.project').mouseenter(function() {
    $( this )
        .find('.info').fadeIn(200);
    $( this )
        .find('div.image').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15 );
});

$('.project').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.info').fadeOut();
    $( this )
        .find('div.image').fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
});
```

what do i have to do, to regulate the animation?

Comment: What have you tried.  What's the relevant code?  http://www.jsfiddle.net is a more appropriate way of demonstrating your problem.

Comment: You ar right: http://jsfiddle.net/meNK5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use jquery's [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the previous animation before starting a new one:

http://jsfiddle.net/meNK5/1/

```
$( this ).find('.info').stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.one('mouseenter', myFunc)` instead of `.mouseenter(myFunc)`

http://api.jquery.com/one/

EDIT: If you want to do the animation multiple times, but not have two animations overlap, recommend using `.is(':animated');`:

```
$('.project').mouseenter(function() {
    if(! $(this).is(':animated')) {
        // start a new animation ...
    }
});
```

A bit more involved solution which could give you more control is the following: introduce two different states to your object, most easily accomplished by using a class with (`.toggleClass()`). jQuery does something similar under the hood for `':animated'`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the idea is to do it once **ever** but rather to not let the animations stack.

Comment: Ah I see. The edit question makes it a bit clearer. I'll update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing it (maybe not the most proper way), is to set a variable on your mouseenter function, and disable it at the end of your animation. Something like (this is pseudo code):

```
var active = 0;
$('#myObject').mouseenter(function() {
    if(active == 0) {
        active = 1;
        startAnimation();
    }
}

function startAnimation(){
    // start my animation
    ...
    // end of animation
    active = 0;
}
```

Comment: You can instead use `.is(":animated")` to see if an animation is already in progress.